# Installing Ubuntu OpenStack: The Canonical distribution” failed : problem with juju bootstrap

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack, cloud

We are trying to setup the cloud using ubuntu server 14.04. We have deployed MAAS successfully on machine that have two NIC cards. Also added images to MAAS. The another node is also booted using PXE and its status is ready. But
openstack installation is failing with following error :

```
[DEBUG: 07-28 14:44:26, multi_install.py:156] Problem during bootstrap: '{'output': '', 'status': 1, 'err': 'Bootstrapping environment "maas"\nStarting new instance for initial state server\nLaunching instance\nWARNING no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node\n - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-4333ae62-3502-11e5-a449-1078d2101a9a/\nERROR failed to bootstrap environment: bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-4333ae62-3502-11e5-a449-1078d2101a9a/" failed to deploy\n'}'
[DEBUG: 07-28 14:44:26, utils.py:62] Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 77, in run
   super().run()
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_continue
   self.installer.do_install()
 File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 157, in do_install
   raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
```

Can anyone guide on this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you import an ssh key to your MAAS user and simply try to "deploy" a node. See if it comes up, transitions to "deployed" and if you can ssh into it with that key as the ubuntu user.